# Guardar gráficos generados con plotly en formato tiff o eps

Tags: r, rstudio

Estoy intentando guardar una serie de gráficos que creo con `plotly`. El formato de alta calidad en que deseo guardar las imágenes es tiff o eps.

Intento para guardar la figura en formato tiff:

```
tiff(file="saving_plot3.tiff",
     width=6, height=4, units="in", res=100)
fig<-plot_ly(OUT, x = ~Estatus, color = ~Condition) %>%
  add_histogram()
dev.off()
```

El código que uso para intentar guardar en formato eps es:

```
setEPS()
postscript("whatever.eps")
fig<-plot_ly(OUT, x = ~Estatus, color = ~Condition) %>%
      add_histogram()
dev.off()
```

En ambos casos la imagen que guardo aparece en blanco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que estás intentando funciona bien cuando se trata de gráficos que se muestran en el panel de los "plots", pero `plotly` no produce gráficos, sino visualizaciones interactivas mediante html + js, algo totalmente distinto.

Para salvar una imagen, tienes en la visualización del propio `plotly` un botón para exportar la gráfica a un archivo `png`. Ahora si quieres algo más configurable, la forma "oficial" es por medio de [`orca()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/plotly/versions/4.9.0/topics/orca), deberás instalar primero `orca` según se documenta en la [página del proyecto](https://github.com/plotly/orca), pero lo más sencillo, a mi criterio, es usar `docker`:

```
docker pull quay.io/plotly/orca
docker run -d -p 9091:9091 quay.io/plotly/orca
```

Luego, simplemente, habrá que llamar a la función `orca()`, por ejemplo:

```
library(plotly)

if (!require("processx")) install.packages("processx")
fig <- plot_ly(z = ~volcano) %>% add_surface()
orca(fig, "surface-plot.svg")
```